# How do I enable quickswitch?

Tags: counter-strike

For both CS and CS:OZ, I cannot find any options to enable fast weapon switch, also known as quickswitch.  It's somewhat frustrating, as I hate switching to the other weapon then pressing the mouse.

Is there a console command to enable quickswitch? I've tried looking for an Advanced setting, but the only option is to change weather effects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can enable quickswitch through the console. After opening the console with <kbd>`</kbd>, use `hud_fastswitch 1` to enable quickswitch, or `hud_fastswitch 0` to disable quickswitch.